# Firefox always prompts to save password on every location change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, react-router, react-router-redux

Firefox (56.0.2 64 Bit on Windows) always asks to save the login for my page on every location change.

If I change the location from /store to /user or something like that Firefox asks again.

Example: https://example.com/store to https://example.com/user

The page is made with love, react, redux, webpack, react-router (browserHistory) and react-router-redux.

It's the same problem on other PC's with Firefox. 
Other browsers working correct.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed through an update of the react tool-chain.